# Select2 User Select Add a new Company Popup Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, bootbox

I have this Company control that list all the company from the database. I also added this `Add a New Company...` -1 which I would like the user to select if they want to add a new company. Once they select that -1 I wanted to use this bootbox.dialog to display all the information needed to create a new company. Any help would be great I did try to create a  jsfiddle example but its not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/tjmcdevitt/12k6zbcp/30/

Comment: you're asking how to make a modal window based on the select option item? Are you using a js or css framework (like bootstrap)? Your question will get better traction if you are clear about what you need help with and show the code you've tried to get there

Comment: Yes I am using js and bootstrap I would just need a new text box to display with a Add and Cancel button